# Windows error 5: Access is denied when trying delete a directory in windows

Tags: python-2.7, windowserror

i am trying to delete a directory but when i run the code it gives windows error 5: access is denied. here is my code: in the Release folder, there is a folder called `OD`.

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(get_path_for_output,'Release')):
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(get_path_for_output,'Release'))
```

the error is like:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\marahama\\Desktop\\Abdur_Release\\Release\\OD\\automations\\GEM\\FMS_adapter.py'
```

Comment: Someone is using the file somewhere. Perhaps that's the same file you're running?

Comment: no. i think. i have checked already.

Comment: Close all programs and cmd prompt windows and try again, something has a file lock.

Comment: yes. the issue has been solved. the file was in read_only mode.

Comment: It may be Possible, When You Open That Folder and then apply rmtree command. Means, You opened that folder.

Answer (score 4):

This was due to the file permissions issue.

You need to have the permissions to perform that task on that file.

To get the permissions associated with a file, use`os.stat(fileName)`

You can explicitly check the write permission for that file using `os.access(fileName, os.W_OK)`

Then, to change the permission, `os.chmod(fileName,permissionNumeric)`.

Ex: `os.chmod(fileName, '0777')`

To change the permission for the current file that is being executed, 
use `os.chmod(__file__, '0777')`

Comment: I got `TypeError: an integer is required` and changing `'0777'` to `0777` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use pydev. And my solution is:

1. Stop Eclipse.
2. Start Eclipse with option **Run as administrator**

Answer (score 0):

```
takeown /F C:\<dir> /R /A
icacls C:\<dir> /grant administrators:F /t
```

Give ownership to administrators and give full control to administrators, if your user is an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

in order to change files located in "C:" you must have admin privileges,
you can either get them before starting the script or while doing so, for instance:

```
#!python
# coding: utf-8
import sys
import ctypes

def run_as_admin(argv=None, debug=False):
    shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32
    if argv is None and shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        return True

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        # Support pyinstaller wrapped program.
        arguments = map(unicode, argv[1:])
    else:
        arguments = map(unicode, argv)
    argument_line = u' '.join(arguments)
    executable = unicode(sys.executable)
    if debug:
        print 'Command line: ', executable, argument_line
    ret = shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", executable, argument_line, None, 1)
    if int(ret) <= 32:
        return False
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = run_as_admin()
    if ret is True:
        print 'I have admin privilege.'
        raw_input('Press ENTER to exit.')
    elif ret is None:
        print 'I am elevating to admin privilege.'
        raw_input('Press ENTER to exit.')
    else:
        print 'Error(ret=%d): cannot elevate privilege.' % (ret, )
```

code taken from: [How to run python script with elevated privilege on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows)

script by: Gary Lee